# How to make a new prediction with GaussianNB in SKLEARN

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gaussian, naivebayes

I've been stuck on this all day. Been following [this](http://dataaspirant.com/2017/02/20/gaussian-naive-bayes-classifier-implementation-python/) tutorial where they implement `GaussianNB` with Sklearn using a publicly available income dataset.

All I'm trying to figure out is how, once I have trained my model, I can make predictions on the fly.

An example from the dataset:

```
39, State-gov, 77516, Bachelors, 13, Never-married, Adm-clerical, Not-in-family, White, Male, 2174, 0, 40, United-States, <=50K
50, Self-emp-not-inc, 83311, Bachelors, 13, Married-civ-spouse, Exec-managerial, Husband, White, Male, 0, 0, 13, United-States, <=50K
38, Private, 215646, HS-grad, 9, Divorced, Handlers-cleaners, Not-in-family, White, Male, 0, 0, 40, United-States, <=50K
53, Private, 234721, 11th, 7, Married-civ-spouse, Handlers-cleaners, Husband, Black, Male, 0, 0, 40, United-States, <=50K
```

Their code:

```
# Required Python Machine learning Packages
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# For preprocessing the data
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
from sklearn import preprocessing
# To split the dataset into train and test datasets
# To model the Gaussian Navie Bayes classifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
# To calculate the accuracy score of the model
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import os
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

adult_df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "adult.data"),
                       header=None, delimiter=' *, *', engine='python')

adult_df.columns = ['age', 'workclass', 'fnlwgt', 'education', 'education_num',
                    'marital_status', 'occupation', 'relationship',
                    'race', 'sex', 'capital_gain', 'capital_loss',
                    'hours_per_week', 'native_country', 'income']

adult_df_rev = adult_df

adult_df_rev.describe(include='all')

for value in ['workclass', 'education',
              'marital_status', 'occupation',
              'relationship', 'race', 'sex',
              'native_country', 'income']:
    adult_df_rev[value].replace(['?'], [adult_df_rev.describe(include='all')[value][2]],
                                inplace=True)


le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
workclass_cat = le.fit_transform(adult_df.workclass)
education_cat = le.fit_transform(adult_df.education)
marital_cat = le.fit_transform(adult_df.marital_status)
occupation_cat = le.fit_transform(adult_df.occupation)
relationship_cat = le.fit_transform(adult_df.relationship)
race_cat = le.fit_transform(adult_df.race)
sex_cat = le.fit_transform(adult_df.sex)
native_country_cat = le.fit_transform(adult_df.native_country)

# initialize the encoded categorical columns
adult_df_rev['workclass_cat'] = workclass_cat
adult_df_rev['education_cat'] = education_cat
adult_df_rev['marital_cat'] = marital_cat
adult_df_rev['occupation_cat'] = occupation_cat
adult_df_rev['relationship_cat'] = relationship_cat
adult_df_rev['race_cat'] = race_cat
adult_df_rev['sex_cat'] = sex_cat
adult_df_rev['native_country_cat'] = native_country_cat

# drop the old categorical columns from dataframe
dummy_fields = ['workclass', 'education', 'marital_status',
                'occupation', 'relationship', 'race',
                'sex', 'native_country']
adult_df_rev = adult_df_rev.drop(dummy_fields, axis=1)

adult_df_rev = adult_df_rev.reindex_axis(['age', 'workclass_cat', 'fnlwgt', 'education_cat',
                                          'education_num', 'marital_cat', 'occupation_cat',
                                          'relationship_cat', 'race_cat', 'sex_cat', 'capital_gain',
                                          'capital_loss', 'hours_per_week', 'native_country_cat',
                                          'income'], axis=1)

adult_df_rev.head(1)

num_features = ['age', 'workclass_cat', 'fnlwgt', 'education_cat', 'education_num',
                'marital_cat', 'occupation_cat', 'relationship_cat', 'race_cat',
                'sex_cat', 'capital_gain', 'capital_loss', 'hours_per_week',
                'native_country_cat']

scaled_features = {}
for each in num_features:
    mean, std = adult_df_rev[each].mean(), adult_df_rev[each].std()
    scaled_features[each] = [mean, std]
    adult_df_rev.loc[:, each] = (adult_df_rev[each] - mean)/std

features = adult_df_rev.values[:, :14]
target = adult_df_rev.values[:, 14]
features_train, features_test, target_train, target_test = train_test_split(features,
                                                                            target, test_size=0.33, random_state=10)
clf = GaussianNB()
clf.fit(features_train, target_train)
target_pred = clf.predict(features_test)


print(target_pred)

print(accuracy_score(target_test, target_pred, normalize = True))
```

Let's imagine I have the following data now from somewhere (`39, State-gov, 77516, Bachelors, 13, Never-married, Adm-clerical, Not-in-family, White, Male, 2174, 0, 40, United-States, <=50K`), and I wish to make a prediction using the model, please can you guide me on how to do this?

I tried 
`clf.predict([[39, "State-gov", 77516, "Bachelors", 13, "Never-married", "Adm-clerical", "Not-in-family", "White", "Male", 2174, 0, 40, "United-States", "<=50K"]])`, but got nothing apart from a lot of errors.

Comment: This is going to take quite some work. You need to pass the new sample through the same preprocessing steps as the data used for training. What you finally pass to `clf.predict()` should look similar to the rows in `features_train` and `features_test`. Actually, most of the code is related to preprocessing, you'll really need to understand what is going on there. The scaling part will be especially tricky because you need to use `mean` and `std` from training again but the code does not store them.

Comment: Thanks very much, I was able to get it work yesterday by going through the same preprocessing work... I actually ended up rewriting the whole thing.

Comment: @ak1652 can you elaborate on what exactly you did? I imagine you replaced a training set with a new one, trained that and used predict(new_data_test)? Going through the same thing, I don't understand the logic...